# How to merge two datarow cells into one?

Tags: c#, excel, merge

I am trying to merge two datarow cells into one. Here is my initializing code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc;
DataRow dr;

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "Col1";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "Col2";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "Col3";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "Col4";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "Col5";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

This is the code I have for each column in Excel:

```
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Col1"] = "";
dr["Col2"] = "Quarter 1";
dr["Col3"] = "";
dr["Col4"] = "";
dr["Col5"] = "";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

And it will look like this:

[image: Separate Individual Cell]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: Merged Cell]

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can do this? I found it to be rather hard to merge the cells.

Comment: the pictures aren't showing up.

Comment: @radarbob I tried that it comes out as separate column cells, not merged. Yeah I'm trying to illustrate what my intentions are. The last picture is what I'm trying to get. The first picture is what I have right now.

Comment: @tdbeckett I'm not sure what's wrong. It works for me. I've loaded on different browsers and different computers and the pictures are there